# Listing the tables content in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

written a script to print the contents of all the tables present in the database...
but unfortunately i am going wrong somewhere. could anyone please tell me where is the mistake?

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbName";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
  {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM {$row[0]}";
$result_1 = mysql_query($sql_1);
$row_1 = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "$row_1";
}
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

thanks..

Comment: 1) as you can see on the man page http://php.net/mysql_query you should switch to PDO or mysqli 2)where's the problem the first query or the second?

Comment: also.. why are you using that for statement? and did you select the database ? (http://php.net/mysql_select_db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, u don't need

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
```

Also, $row_1 is an array, so to print it use something like

```
print_r($row_1);
```

And there might be not the only row in a table, so use construction like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM {$row[0]}";
$result_1 = mysql_query($sql_1);
while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_row($result_1/*There was also an error*/)) 
   print_r($row_1); /*Print_r or other function to print an array*/
}
```

Comment: Thanku @Ziumin but i m still not able to list all the columns present in the respective tables.  The output is like: table1 table2 table3 .... unable to list the columns present in all the tables